# Error Foreign Key. Missing index. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentado hacer una aplicación para llevar un conteo de goles en una serie de partidos. Donde los jugadores pueden cambiar de equipos según el dia y pueden faltar un dia si y otro no.
Aquí dejo el script generado:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Wed Sep  8 21:19:24 2021
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
  `id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `admin` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Jugadores`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Jugadores` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Jugadores` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `goles` INT NULL,
  `fecha_partido` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Partido`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Partido` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Partido` (
  `id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `dia` DATE NOT NULL,
  `jugador_1` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_2` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_3` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_4` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_5` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_6` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_7` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_8` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_9` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_10` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_11` INT NULL,
  `jugador_12` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `jugador1_nombre_idx` (`jugador_1` ASC, `jugador_2` ASC, `jugador_3` ASC, `jugador_4` ASC, `jugador_5` ASC, `jugador_6` ASC, `jugador_7` ASC, `jugador_8` ASC, `jugador_9` ASC, `jugador_10` ASC, `jugador_11` ASC, `jugador_12` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador1_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_1` , `jugador_2` , `jugador_3` , `jugador_4` , `jugador_5` , `jugador_6` , `jugador_7` , `jugador_8` , `jugador_9` , `jugador_10` , `jugador_11` , `jugador_12`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

El error es el siguiente:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Partido` (   `id` VARCHAR(16) NOT
> NULL,   `dia` DATE NOT NULL,   `jugador_1` INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_2`
> INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_3` INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_4` INT NOT NULL,
> `jugador_5` INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_6` INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_7`
> INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_8` INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_9` INT NOT NULL,
> `jugador_10` INT NOT NULL,   `jugador_11` INT NULL,   `jugador_12` INT
> NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   INDEX `jugador1_nombre_idx` (`jugador_1`
> ASC, `jugador_2` ASC, `jugador_3` ASC, `jugador_4` ASC, `jugador_5`
> ASC, `jugador_6` ASC, `jugador_7` ASC, `jugador_8` ASC, `jugador_9`
> ASC, `jugador_10` ASC, `jugador_11` ASC, `jugador_12` ASC) VISIBLE,
> CONSTRAINT `jugador1_nombre`     FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_1` ,
> `jugador_2` , `jugador_3` , `jugador_4` , `jugador_5` , `jugador_6` ,
> `jugador_7` , `jugador_8` , `jugador_9` , `jugador_10` , `jugador_11`
> , `jugador_12`)     REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id` , `id` , `id`
> , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id` , `id`)     ON
> DELETE RESTRICT     ON UPDATE RESTRICT) ENGINE = InnoDB   Error Code:
> 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'jugador1_nombre' in the referenced table 'jugadores'    0.000
> sec

Comment: El problema aquí es un mal diseño que no soporta siquiera una sustitución de jugador, algo habitual en cualquier partido. Deberías tener una tercera tabla para expresar las jugadores que intervienen en un `partido`, digamos que esa tabla se llama `jugador_partido` y tendría las siguientes columnas: `id_partido, id_jugador`  y **tendría tantas filas como jugadores intervengan en ese partido**. Meter doce columnas en una fila es una pésima idea, ¿cómo expresarás las sustituciones de jugadores? ÉSE es el mayor problema aquí, tu modelo de datos sucumbirá a la más mínima situación anómala.

Comment: Y es que tu modelo de datos no resuelve ni el más mínimo requerimiento. Supongamos que quieres saber en cuántos partidos ha jugado el  `jugadorX`  ¿cómo piensas obtener ese dato en una tabla de doce columnas? Sigamos avanzando en nivel de complejidad... ¿cómo piensas controlar en tu modelo la cantidad de goles o lo que sea que anote cada jugador? ¿o el tiempo que cada jugador ha jugado? etc, etc, etc. Como podrás ver, tu tabla de doce columnas no es otra cosa que un lastre y debes pensar seriamente en normalizar.

Comment: A ver, entiendo lo que dices, pero es una aplicación pequeña y para unos amigos. Solo estoy intentando fixear es problema de la foreign key y ya.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres asignar varias veces la columna de una tabla como referencia tendrás que definir cada CONSTRAINT por separado, algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Partido` (
  `id` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `dia` DATE NOT NULL,
  `jugador_1` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_2` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_3` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_4` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_5` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_6` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_7` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_8` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_9` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_10` INT NOT NULL,
  `jugador_11` INT NULL,
  `jugador_12` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `jugador1_nombre_idx` (`jugador_1` ASC, `jugador_2` ASC, `jugador_3` ASC, `jugador_4` ASC, `jugador_5` ASC, `jugador_6` ASC, `jugador_7` ASC, `jugador_8` ASC, `jugador_9` ASC, `jugador_10` ASC, `jugador_11` ASC, `jugador_12` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `jugador1_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador2_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_2`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador3_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_3`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador4_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_4`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador5_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_5`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador6_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_6`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador7_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_7`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador8_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_8`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador9_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_9`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador10_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_10`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador11_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_11`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `jugador12_nombre_cns`
    FOREIGN KEY (`jugador_12`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

De todos modos, deberías reconsiderar la forma en que estás diseñando tus tablas. Cualquier reporte o mantenimiento de este modelo de datos será harto difícil, y este modelo no se adapta a situaciones tan comunes como que en un partido puedan participar más de doce jugadores (sustitución).